# Windows Store App Javascript - Disable prompt for user credentials when requested by the server

Tags: jquery, rest, windows-store-apps, basic-authentication

I am building a Windows Store App that accesses a RESTful web service using jQuery.  The web service uses Basic Authentication and everything works fine with valid credentials but when the login fails Windows prompts the user for login again (see image).  I want to prevent this and handle the login failure myself.  I've looked into HttpBaseProtocolFilter.AllowUI however I'm not sure if this can work with jQuery.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that jQuery is using XMLHttpRequest under the covers, in which case the prompting happens automatically from within that API. To take advantage of the options in the WinRT HttpClient API, you'd have to tweak jQuery to be making calls through HttpClient instead. One reason that API was added to Win8.1 is for exactly these kinds of scenarios, as XMLHttpRequest (and WinJS.xhr which is a wrapper for it) doesn't give you the control you need.

Comment: Thank you, since posting the question I have switched to making the calls through the WinRT HttpClient which allows me to use HttpBaseProtocolFilter.AllowUI.  Setting that to false prevents the prompting and allows me to handle authentication errors myself.

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear it. The WinRT API will give you all the flexibility and controls that you should need, which is why it was added.